# Using Selenium WebDriverRemote to start Chrome with command line arguments

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need to capture the Chrome console-debug.log file.
e.g.

```
chrome.exe --enable-logging
```

This dumps a console-debug.log file in the UserData folder. I tested this manually and it works.

I can't see to use Selenium to load Chrome remotely with arguments.

I have checked out the docs here and tried to follow 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Now I have two machines, one is a linux machine that hosts my python test code and another is a Windows VM that I run Chrome on for testing against different urls.

The Windows VM has Selenium standalone server 2.45.0 and its' start-up script points to the location of chromedriver.exe (version 2.23.409699). It also starts IEDriverServer but we don't use that right now. I start it using a batch file in the Startup folder that has the line.

```
java -jar C:\Users\Remote\Desktop\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\Remote\Desktop\selenium\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\Remote\Desktop\selenium\webdrivers\IEDriverServer.exe
```

On the linux machine I am using a Python implementation, and we use webdriver.Remote to connect to Selenium standalone server. For debug purposes I'm running PyCharm so I can step through the code.

The code I use to setup the connection is:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
caps = options.to_capabilities()

self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://%s:4444/wd/hub' % browser_host_ip_address,
        desired_capabilities=caps,
        proxy=proxy)
```

If I step through with PyCharm and monitor the caps object just before going in to the webdriver.Remote code I get an object that looks like this:

```
{'chromeOptions': {'args': ['--enable-logging'], 'extensions': []}, 'javascriptEnabled': True, 'platform': 'ANY', 'browserName': 'chrome', 'version': ''}
```

This chromeOptions object makes it all the way to the Selenium standalone server and that then outputs to the server console:

```
10:59:41.109 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, chromeOptions={args=[--enable-logging], extensions=[]}, version=, platform=ANY}]]
```

This then doesn't seem to make it through to chromedriver. I created a simple C program that outputs any arguments passed to it and replaced chromedriver with this and the only arguments passed to it were the --port=xxxxx where x is a number.

So chromeOptions makes it all the way through but fails at the Selenium server. I imagine I am doing something silly but for the life of me I can't work out what.

I have tried the latest version of Selenium standalone server 3.0 beta 2 and 2.53.1, and also 2.39.0 in case something was brought in to stop it. I have also tried multiple chromedriver versions.

I am assuming my original premise that I can use chromeOptions in this way is wrong, but I'm not sure.

I need to use 2 different machines so I assume I would need a webdriver.Remote object as webdriver.Chrome doesn't support remote connections. Is that true?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated?

Adam